# No connection between my Flask Container and the Ganache Container

Tags: python, docker, flask, docker-compose, ganache

I want to connect my Flask Docker container to the Ganache Docker container. The Ganache container works without problems. 
I connect the Flask App locally to the Ganache Container everything works. But if I use my Flask Container the app can't connect to the Ganache Container.

My docker-compose file:

```
version: "3"
services:
    app:
        image: flask-api
        build:
             context: .
             dockerfile: Dockerfile-flask-api
        ports:
             - '5000:5000'
        volumes:
             - ./app:/app
        depends_on:
             - blockchain
    blockchain:
        image: trufflesuite/ganache-cli:latest
        ports:
             - '8545:8545'
```

My Dockerfile for the Flask application:

```
FROM python:3.7

WORKDIR /test
ADD test /test

EXPOSE 5000

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ENTRYPOINT ["python", "app.py"]
```

With the following command I call the Ganache Container in the Flask App

```
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("http://0.0.0.0:8545"))
```

I execute the application by `docker-compose up. I get the following error message

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='0.0.0.0', port=8545)
```

Maybe somebody can help me with the problem.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change :

```
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("http://0.0.0.0:8545"))
```

to :

```
web3 = Web3(HTTPProvider("http://blockchain:8545"))
```

When you set up containers from compose they are all connected to the default network created by compose. `blockchain` is in this case the DNS name of `blockchain` container and will be resolved to container IP automatically.

Comment: have just tried this and get the following error message `HTTPConnectionPool(host='blockchain', port=8545): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f2ad64d0400>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))`

Comment: are you able to connect to `blockchain` service from your host?

Comment: When I run `docker-compose up app blockchain` I get the error message again. But if I first run `docker-compose up blockchain` and then `docker-compose up app` it works. Why is that so?

Comment: Because your blockchain continer might not have been fully initialized to accept connections before `app` container tried to reach it. And when you spawn your services while specyfing service names you probably did it in long enought time interval so that blockchain container was initialized before app container tried to reach it. Check [this](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. With `restart: always` I have been able to solve the error